# Modeless shell not visible after set visible to true

Tags: java, window, swt, visibility

I'm using SWT 4.4.2 (win32) to build the Graphical User Interface for a simple test application.
By pressing a button or menu item I want to show a new window. But this window should not be a modal dialog. It should be a kind of overlay window so the application is not blocked.

First at startup I'm creating all necessary components of my program:

```
private void initUI() {
    mainWindow = new Shell(display);
    ...

    overlayWindow = new Shell(mainWindow, SWT.MODELESS);
    overlayWindow.setLocation(200, 200);
    overlayWindow.setSize(160, 33);
    overlayWindow.setText("Overlay");
    overlayWindow.setVisible(false);

    label = new Label(overlayWindow, SWT.CENTER);
    label.setLocation(10, 10);
    label.setSize(140, 13);
    label.setText("Test");
}
```

Later I check whether the overlay window is viisble because the visibility depends on some program options and if the window is hidden at this time I want to show it:

```
if (!overlayWindow.getVisible()) {
  overlayWindow.setVisible(true);
  overlayWindow.setFocus();
}
```

I'm very new in SWT so I hope I did nothing wrong.
My problem is that the visibility is set to true (debugged) but I can't see the window with the "Test" message. There's always only the main window visible.

Answer (score 0):

(This does not not necessarily answer the question but posting the code in a comment wouldn't work)

I think the problem must be somewhere in the code that you left out. If I complete the provided code like so, it works as expected:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  Display display = new Display();
  // create and open main shell
  Shell mainShell = new Shell( display );
  mainShell.setText( "Main" );
  mainShell.open();
  // create overlay shell
  final Shell overlayShell = new Shell( mainShell, SWT.MODELESS );
  overlayShell.setLocation( 200, 200 );
  overlayShell.setSize( 160, 33 );
  overlayShell.setText( "Overlay" );
  // add mouse-down listener that opens overlay shell
  mainShell.addListener( SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent( Event event ) {
      overlayShell.setVisible( true );
      overlayShell.setFocus();
    }
  } );

  while( !mainShell.isDisposed() ) {
    if( !display.readAndDispatch() )
      display.sleep();
  }
  display.dispose();
}
```

Click on the main shell and the overlay shell will open. Note that the overlay shell has only a thin black border and no title bar.

[image: Screenshot of overlay shell]